# Inflating open sets up to homotopy through CW skeletons

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

In preparation for an upcoming exam, I’m working through old exercises.

> Let $X$ be a CW complex with skeletons $X^0 ⊂ X^1 ⊂ … ⊂ X$. Show that for any open $U ⊂ X^{n-1}$ there is an open $V ⊂ X^{n}$ such that $U ⊂ V$ and the inclusion $U → V$ is a homotopy equivalence.

I’m using a pushout definition of CW complexes:

- $X$ has the final topology with respect to all inclusions $X^n ⊂ X$.
- For every $n$ there is a set $I_n$, indexing $n$-disks, so that we have a pushout square:
  \begin{align*}
   \require{AMScd}
   \begin{CD}
    \coprod_\smash{I_n} S^{n-1} @>{⊂}>> \coprod_\smash{I_n} D^n\\
    @V{φ}VV @VV{φ}V \\
    X^{n-1} @>>{⊂}> X^n
   \end{CD}
  \end{align*}

Okay, what I have done and know:

- $\hat U := φ^{-1} (U)$ is open in $\coprod S^{n-1}$.
- $\hat V := \{x ∈ \coprod D^n\setminus \{0\}; \frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert} ∈ \hat U\}$ is open in $\coprod D^n$.
- $\hat U ⊂ \hat V$ is a deformation retract.

Set $V := U ∪ φ(V)$. I feel like, if I roll up my sleeves, I’m able to prove that

1. $V ∩ X^{n-1} = U$, and
2. $φ^{-1}(V) = \hat V$,

so that $V ⊂ X^n$ is indeed open. (Although I’d like to see hints for how to do that with the categorical notion of a pushout, in the same spirit of what I’ve done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098938/the-pushout-of-an-open-closed-injective-map-is-open-closed).)

> But how can I show that the inclusion $U → V$ is indeed a homotopy equivalence?

I want to use the deformation retract $\hat U → \hat V$, of course, but I don’t see how I can really push it down to $U → V$.